# Executables deployment in multiple servers regularly

Tags: shell, deployment, executable, server-side

If there is a code base and many servers, how should I deploy the executable in multiple servers regularly? I need a script to do this

Comment: You can create a basic script that copies the file (with `sftp` or `scp`, for example). Then you can loop through a list of servers that can be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

There are many system management tools. Chef is what we use, it is great but there is a bit of a learning curve. You may want to look into your OS's default package manager and distribute packages of your code base.